# contactform7 how attach any types files

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

earlier to attach files of any type to an email i commented lines in /modules/file.php

```
/* File type validation */ 

$file_type_pattern = wpcf7_acceptable_filetypes(
    $tag->get_option( 'filetypes' ), 'regex'
);

$file_type_pattern = '/\.(' . $file_type_pattern . ')$/i';

if ( empty( $file['name'] )
or ! preg_match( $file_type_pattern, $file['name'] ) ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag,
        wpcf7_get_message( 'upload_file_type_invalid' )
    );

    return $result;
}
```

this trick worked on version 5.3

after update does not work anymore

Anyone have any ideas how to get around this limitation without explicitly specifying allowed file types in plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify acceptable file types inside form tag:

`[file file-123 filetypes:gif|png|jpg|jpeg]`

https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Upd. It's might no way to specify any file type without editing plugin files now. Maybe it's better to determine what types of files exactly should be accepted. For example, it's not safe to allow `.php` files.